# Watir: my browser.button(:class=>'').click is not working

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I have the following HTML Structure:

```
<button class="btn btn-add" data-role="add">Add New User</button>
```

I am trying to get the class name in my ruby-watir script which is:     `browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add').click`,
but it doesn't work.

How can I click that button using watir?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens?  Is there an error or a stacktrace?

Comment: Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:class=>"", :tag_name=>"button"} but now its working already, but I need to have sleep 3 or sleep 5

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `when_present` to poll for the element to become present: `browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add').when_present.click`

Comment: I try to have that one "browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add').when_present.click " without sleep 5...  but still it doesn't work.... and the error is still the same..... but when I put back the sleep 5, it works already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many buttons with the same class are there in your page anyway?

```
  browser.buttons(:class => "btn btn-add").count
```

usually when_present should take care of the timing issue, add another identifier to help locate the proper element

```
    browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add', :text => 'Add New User').when_present.click
```

Also try this (additional line of code, but could help with the timing issue):

```
  Watir::Wait.until { browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add').visible? }<br>
  browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add', :text => 'Add New User').click
```

You can also try regex to find your button

```
browser.button(:text => /Add New User/).when_present.click
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with Ruby but you can fix it by adding text attribute (Add New User) to the locator.

like: `//button[@class='btn btn-add' and text()='Add New User']`

If still doesn't work, as you tried you have to wait for some time using sleep. Though webdriver waits until the entire page is loaded, some elements may take some more time to display/enable.